Run script as part of Relase Output Job in Altium
I need to run a script as last step of a Release Output Job in Altium Designer.
Specifically, I need to run a Python script, but this detail should not matter.
How can this be achieved?

This may be achieved by directing your very specific questions regarding Altium scripts to the very popular Altium Technical Support, or otherwise their very helpful forum....
